# Declare different type of variables using switch

Tags: c#, variables, switch-statement

I am trying to create a new variable based on a particular value received from a function.

The variable can be of different classes.

Here's what I am trying:

```
switch (request)
{
    case "ClassA":
        {
            var x = new ClassA();
            break;
        }
    case "ClassB":
        {
            var x = new ClassB();
            break;
        } 
    case "ClassC":
        {
            var x = new ClassC();
            break;
        } 
    case "ClassD":
        {
            var x = new ClassD();
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
}
```

This is fine till here and no issues. The issue arises, when I try to use the value of `x` out of the scope of the switch statement. The system says that `x` does not exists in the current context.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Once outside the `switch` block, `x` is gone. You should declare x before you enter any of the `switch` statements.

Comment: I know that... but I can not declare x out side of the switch box. I have to decide the type of x based on switch.

Comment: use dynamic instead of var

Comment: This is terrible.  However, the solution probably won't work in your case.  Can you [edit] and tell us *what your goal is with this code?* This is the X/Y problem.  "I need to do X" "The hell you do.  Do Y."

Comment: This looks like Class A, B, C, and D should inherit from a common parent class. That way you could use polymorphism. This only makes sense if they have some related purpose that you use later though.

Comment: Do you have the source for `ClassA`, `ClassB`, etc?

Comment: `ClassA`, `ClassB`, ..., `ClassD` would have to have a common supertype (i.e. a common base class or interface implementation). You could then declare `x` as that type before the `switch` statement. Other than that, what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense in a statically-typed type system such as C#'s.

Comment: The goal with this code is to create a variable of type received in the request variable

Comment: The question is what you actually want to achieve by writing this code, not what you want to get compiled (also now you have answers how to get it to compile you probably should ask new clear question).

Comment: "The goal with this code is to create a variable of type received in the request variable" - have you thought of creating a generic method?

Comment: This looks like a bad implementation for a bad idea. Reconsider the design

Comment: I bet your goal isn't to "create a new variable based on a particular value received from a function". Your goal is probably something else you want to achieve later on. So, *if* it was possible to do what you're asking, what would you attempt to do next?

Comment: It actually is the same.. I am sending the type of the variable I need to declare... anyways... the issue seems to be resolved now.. 'dynamic' worked like charm...

Comment: but notice that using dynamic is not always good. its slow. because the compiler decides about the type of variable in runtime. so code design is important too.try to use dynamic in rare cases.not always.

Comment: Switch and dynamic?!?? My eyes are bleeding. Code really cannot get worse than this.

Comment: To All the haters(who down voted): there may be a number of situations, that you may not be aware of... if there is nothing good to add.. please go check some other questions..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must declare `x` outside `switch`. and declare it only once. and if classes does not have same parent you must use `dynamic` as a type of x.

```
ParentClass x = null;// dynamic x = null; in case that x is not known type
switch (request)
        {
            case "ClassA":
                {
                    x = new ClassA();
                    break;
                }
            case "ClassB":
                {
                    x = new ClassB();
                    break;
                } 
            case "ClassC":
                {
                    x = new ClassC();
                    break;
                } 
            case "ClassD":
                {
                    x = new ClassD();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a good place for an `interface` or `abstract class`.

Basically, to most easily solve your issue, you would implement an `interface` as follows:

```
interface IDescriptiveName
{
    DescriptiveNameType Type { get; }
}

enum DescriptiveNameType
{
    ClassA
}
```

Each class would then implement `DescriptiveNameType Type` and return their type. (Generally `DescriptiveNameType` is an `enum`.) I.e.

```
public class ClassA : IDescriptiveName
{
    public DescriptiveNameType Type { get { return DescriptiveNameType.ClassA; } }
}
```

Then, based on the value of `ClassA.Type` (which for `ClassA` would be `ClassA`) you could cast `x` and work with it.

```
IDescriptiveName x = null;

// original switch logic simply remove var

if (x.Type == DescriptiveNameType.ClassA)
{
    // do something for ClassA
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a switch statement, use a `Dictionary` to provide the class lookup:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<object>> classLookup = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>
{
    { "ClassA", () => new ClassA() },
    { "ClassB", () => new ClassB() },
    { "ClassC", () => new ClassC() },
    { "ClassD", () => new ClassD() }
};

public object GetObject(string className)
{
    return classLookup.ContainsKey(className)
        ? classLookup[className]()
        : null;
}
```

Comment: This snippet did not do any good.. I tried it but it gave compilation error telling that the members that I am trying to access are not available. I am not saying here that your code is not good.. it is very good.. just that my situation is a little weird..